# I keep getting an error of non-invocable member system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem,dataitem

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
   <HeaderTemplate>
   <table>
       <tr>
           <th>Term</th>
           <th>Definition Number</th>
           <th>Definitnion Version Number </th>
           <th>Definition</th>
           <th>Amplifying Explanation Text</th>
           <th>See Also</th>
           <th>Authoritative Source</th>
           <th>Scope</th>
           <th>Domain</th>
           <th>Governance State</th>
           <th>Last Updated Time</th>
       </tr>

   </HeaderTemplate>

   <ItemTemplate>
       <tr>
         <td><%# Container.DataItem("TermText") %></td> // This is where i am getting the error
           <td><%# Container.DataItem("DefNbr") %></td>
           <td><%# Container.DataItem("DefVerNbr") %></td>
           <td><%# Container.DataItem("DefText") %></td>
           <td><%# Container.DataItem("AmplifyingExplanationText") %></td>
           <td><%# Container.DataItem("SeeAlsoText") %></td>
           <td><%# Container.DataItem("AuthoritativeSrcText") %></td>
           <td><%# Container.DataItem("ScopeName") %></td>
           <td><%# Container.DataItem("DomnName") %></td>
           <td><%# Container.DataItem("GovernanceStateName") %></td>
           <td><%# Container.DataItem("LastUpdtTimestamp") %></td>

       </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>

   <FooterTemplate>
   </table>
   </FooterTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>

   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Glossary %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [TermText], [DefNbr], [DefVerNbr], [DefText], [AmplifyingExplanationText], [SeeAlsoText], [AuthoritativeSrcText], [ScopeName], [DomnName], [GovernanceStateName], [LastUpdtTimestamp] FROM [Glossary] ORDER BY [TermText]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

   </asp:Content>
```

Not sure what im doing wrong. I followed the instructions exactly. Im trying to use a particular table to display and be able to filter results using the datatables js library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this instead (replace all your versions with this instead):

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DB_COLUMN_NAME").ToString() %>
```

SO:

```
<td><%# Container.DataItem("TermText") %></td>
```

Would be:

```
<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TermText").ToString() %></td>
```

Comment: Tick it as the answer if it is :)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not valid. Try changing

```
Container.DataItem(...)
```

by

```
Eval(...)
```